# How to stop service from running when app loads in angularJS Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've created a simple login app that uses local storage. I have a controller.js file and a service.js file.

Ok in my controller everything is set up correctly, I'm calling the service in correctly. I'm setting a `localStorageService` which holds a default Prod url. If the user wants to hit another url I have a `Button-Bar` where they can select another url and it overwrites the default url.

When I hit the login button to run the service it still uses the default url. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong. Below is my code.

Controller.js

```
 app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $ionicModal, localStorageService, $location, loginDataStructure, loginAuthenticateService) {

//setting button count to zero on start
$scope.tapCount = 0;

//create url variable
var url;

$scope.baseUrl = function (){

$scope.tapCount++;

console.log('tapCount ='+ $scope.tapCount)

//setting url if user wants to change it.
$scope.setUrl = function(urlShort){

   if(urlShort == 'PROD'){
     url = 'https://www.prod.com/api';
   }else if(urlShort == 'DEV'){
     url = 'https://dev.dev.com/api';
   }else if(urlShort == 'UAT'){
     url = 'https://uat.uat.com/api';
   }else if(urlShort == 'QA'){
     url = 'https://qa.qa.com/api';
   }else{
   url = 'https://www.prod.com/api';
}
  localStorageService.set('baseURL', url );
}

 //login button

  $scope.login = function(data) {

  if (typeof(data) == 'undefined' || data === null) {
        data = [];
     }

        $ionicLoading.show({
            noBackdrop: true,
            template: '<ion-spinner class="spinner-positive" icon="lines"/></ion-spinner><p class="item-icon-center">Loading</p>'
        });

        console.log('login data = ' + data.username + " " + data.password)

        $scope.fromService = loginDataStructure.getUsers(data.username, data.password);
        console.log('from service', $scope.fromService);


        loginAuthenticateService.all($scope.fromService).then(function(JWTData) {

            $scope.showAlert = function(errorText) {

                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({

                    title: 'Error',
                    template: errorText
                });
            }

            var jwt = JWTData;
            var status;

            console.log('data is ', JWTData)

            status = JWTData.status;

            if (status == '0') {
                $scope.showAlert('Something went wrong, please try again laters');
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            } else if (status == '200') {
                // now that the login is valid lets get the rest of the user data using the JWT
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $ionicLoading.show({
                    noBackdrop: true,
                    template: '<ion-spinner class="spinner-positive" icon="lines"/></ion-spinner><p class="item-icon-center">Getting Data</p>'
                });
         }
      }
```

service.js

```
app.service('loginDataStructure', function($http, $q, localStorageService) {

   //setting the url to a variable
   var url =  localStorageService.get('baseURL');
   console.log('url service =',  localStorageService.get('url')

    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;  charset=UTF-8'
    };
    var params = "";

    this.getUsers = function(username, password,url) {
     // var url = ApiEndpoint.url ;
        params = "UsernameOrEmail=" + username + "&Password=" + password;

        console.log('params', params)

        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url+ '/login',
            headers: headers,
            data: params
        };

        return req;


    };

})
```

The above works but if I change the URL from the controller and hit login it doesn''t change the url in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't updating the `url` var in `loginDataStructure` service. The service is a singleton, so localStorageService.get('baseURL') is only being called once, when the service is instantiated.

Here's a couple options:

- Create a `setUrl` function in your `loginDataStructure` service, then call that from `$scope.setUrl` in your controller, or call it from `localStorageService.set()` so that the url gets updated in that service.
- In your `loginDataStructure` service, stick `var url =  localStorageService.get('baseURL');` inside getUsers() so that it pulls in the updated URL each time it's called.